# Does selenium support IE with google frame add on installed on it?

Tags: gwt, google-chrome, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium is able to load Chrome Frame pages. The problem is that once you load the page in IE with Chrome Frame plugin, the  tag appears as empty. Selenium tries to identify elements using the DOM structure, but the way IE and Chrome Frame plugin works, rendering
and DOM tree are taken over by the Chromium code and IE gets an empty DOM.

So i guess, selenium doesn't support IE with google frame add-on installed on it?

Has anyone worked around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This question has been [asked and answered](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-users/Yh5DlaPdlhA) on the Selenium user's mailing list. The IE driver doesn't work with the Google Chrome Frame add-on, and there are no plans to implement support for it to work with the Chrome Frame add-on. Either you want to test the operation of your website under Chrome (in which case you should use the ChromeDriver), or you want to test it under IE (in which case you should use the IE driver). If you can point to a specific case where using the website with the Chrome Frame add-on behaves differently than the way it behaves with the Chrome standalone browser, you might be able to make a case to revisit the issue. Furthermore, remember that Selenium is an Open Source project, and you are welcome to make changes and submit patches to the code at any time.

Comment: I understand that IE driver is mainly created for IE and Chrome Driver is created for chrome. However, in one of my newly work project application, the code is created with GWT or google engine and we were testing in Google chrome for like 3 yrs. Now the top management wants the website to be able to use it in IE which is only possible by adding google frame add-on installed on it. Since we as a automation tool are very small compared to the development team, it's very hard to convince the management that it can't be done. Hope you understand my concern.

Comment: Two things: First, how is your dev team forcing the use of Google Chrome? User agent sniffing? Some other browser detection mechanism? Second, you still haven't provided an answer to the fundamental question, in this forum or any other: Does the website behave differently in the Chrome standalone browser than it does in IE with the ChromeFrame add-in? As the primary developer of the IE driver, I'll be glad to engage with your management team if they have questions.

Comment: Java code they are using uses google engine or GWT and the code is pretty raw and they haven't reached the point where it would work even in IE without adding Google frame add-in. The problem is not with the manual testing since we can easily download add-in in IE and test the website manually. So yes for now, the devs along with management are forcing us to be able to test in IE with GWT as well.

Comment: The selenium works perfectly in Chrome which we have been doing for more than 1 year now but running in IE with GWT, selenium is able to load Chrome Frame pages but once you load the page in IE with Chrome Frame plugin, the <body> tag appears as empty. Selenium tries to identify elements using the DOM structure, but the way IE and Chrome Frame plugin works, rendering and DOM tree are taken over by the Chromium code and IE gets an empty DOM. Hope this answers your second question.

Comment: I understand it's an open source tool and anyone can put a patch on it but if i happen to know so much about selenium that i could create a patch, i would probably not even asking this question :).

Answer (score 0):

Watir WebDriver has the same issue.

Selenium core, the part that loads in the target browser and executes tests does work and can be run independently.  So, if you have a Selenium test suite in HTML form, it can be run in GCF using the following steps:

1. Configure a web server to opt all URLs into chrome frame using HTTP header as described here: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started#TOC-Making-Your-Pages-Work-With-Google-
2. Host your test suite under '/tests' folder on this web server. Lets say the suite is my_test_suite.html.
3. Host the selenium core folder as the '/core' on the server
4. Now restart the server.
5. Run the suite with this URL: http:///core/TestRunner.html?test=tests/my_test_suite.html&auto=true